# How to import 4-digit year value instead of 2-digit using read.csv

Tags: r, date, read.csv, as.date

I need to import dates using read.csv. The date are in "dd-mm-yyyy" format in csv file. I've appended sample data below.

UniqueId    DOB

1. 01-04-1984
2. 24-08-1904
3. 12-12-2006
4. 05-05-1870

Read.csv is converting the date into "dd-mm-yy" format even when I'm importing date as character.
I need it to import all 4-digit year.

My code and results are:

> x <- read.csv("file", header=TRUE,colClasses =c("DOB"="character"))

I also tried:

> x <- read.csv("file", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Result from both:

UniqueId     DOB

1. 01-04-84
2. 24-08-04
3. 12-12-06
4. 05-08-70

> ```
> > class(x$DOB)
> [1] "character"
> ```

When I use as.Date function on this, I get error values:

```
> as.Date(dob$DOB, format="%d-%m-%y")  
[1] "01-04-1984" "24-08-2004" "12-12-2006" "05-08-1970"
```

I read that as.Date function automatically turns years between 00 and 68 into 21st Century years and years between 69 and 99 into 20th Century years.

Thus, I think I'm making a mistake in read.csv function itself.

Comment: The behavior you describe is not consistent with read.csv (it should not manipulate any character or factor columns). Are you sure the date are in "dd-mm-yyyy" format in csv file? How are you viewing the csv file? If you are opening in excel or some other spreadsheet software it may be displaying in "dd-mm-yyyy" despite some other format in csv. If so, open the csv in a text editor to see the actual format.

Comment: `%y` is for 2-digit years, `%Y` is 4-digit years. See `?strptime` for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't figured out the way of achieving what you want in one line, but if you can afford splitting the task into two lines, then try this:

```
library(dplyr) # data frame operations
library(lubridate) # tidyverse-compliant package for operations on dates

x <- read.csv("file.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x <- x %>% mutate(DOB = as.Date(DOB, format="%d-%m-%Y"))
x %>% mutate(year = lubridate::year(DOB)) # just to verify that the operations on dates work as expected
#   UniqueID        DOB year
# 1        1 1984-04-01 1984
# 2        2 1904-08-24 1904
# 3        3 2006-12-12 2006
# 4        4 1870-05-05 1870
```

Comment: Just in case OP isn't a `dplyr` user, the second line `x <- x %>% mutate(DOB = as.Date(DOB, format="%d-%m-%Y"))` is the same as `x$DOB = as.Date(x$DOB, format="%d-%m-%Y")`